# Pullback stability?

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Suppose the following square is a pullback.
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
    E\times _BA @>{\pi_2}>> A\\ @V{\pi_1}VV @VV{\alpha}V\\
    E @>>{p}> B
    \end{CD}$$

The following is proposition 6.5.1 from Borceux & Janelidze's *Galois Theories*:

**Proposition 6.5.1.** Let $\mathcal M$ be a pullback stable class of arrows in $\mathsf{Top}$. Then $\alpha$ locally in $\mathcal M\implies \pi_1$ locally in $\mathcal M$.

Regardless of the definition of "locally in", isn't this exactly the definition of pullback stability for $\mathcal M$?

Comment: What do you mean "regardless of the definition of locally in"? Maybe "locally in" has to do with the number of potatoes produced this year, and then of course it's not exactly the definition of pullback stability... You can't just ignore words in a proposition... Yes, if you remove the words "locally in" in the proposition this is the definition of pullback stability, but the words are there.

Answer (score 1):

No, Proposition 6.5.1. is the statement that the class $\mathcal L$ of morphisms locally in $\mathcal M$ is pullback-stable. This is non-trivial even when $\mathcal M$ is pullback-stable because $\mathcal L$ contains different (strictly more) morphisms than $\mathcal M$ does.

The use of "locally in" is an instance of the [red herring principle](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/red+herring+principle).

> The mathematical red herring principle is the principle that in mathematics, a “red herring” need not, in general, be either red or a herring.
>
> Frequently, in fact, it is conversely true that all herrings are red herrings. This often leads to mathematicians speaking of “non-red herrings,” and sometimes even to a redefinition of “herring” to include both the red and non-red versions.

In this particular case, "in $\mathcal M$" implies "locally in $\mathcal M$", but the converse is false.